# What event is triggered when the value of an input field is changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm using a JavaScript library that occasionally changes the value of an input field. I want to detect when that happens.

Apparently, the `change` and `input` events are not triggered when the value of an input field is changed (at least not on Chrome).

To verify that, I have tried this (using jQuery):

```
<script>
    $(function() {
       $('#inp').on('change',function() { console.log('change event'); });
       $('#inp').on('input',function() { console.log('input event'); });
       $('#inp').val('hello');
    });
</script>
<input type="text" id="inp">
```

Neither the change event nor the input event is triggered when I call `.val('hello')`.

How can I detect the change? (Please remember that the code that changes the value is outside my control, so I cannot add a call to `trigger()` there.)

Comment: in that case I think it is a problem

Comment: does `element.onchange();` fired by the external script ? try it old way with the `addEventListener` function.

Comment: I tried `addEventListener`. It didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a work around, you can pool the value of textbox after regular intervals and trigger the event when it is changed.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/9zeRH/)**

```
$('#elementId').change(function(){
   alert("changed");
});

var previousVal = "";
function InputChangeListener()
{
   if($('#elementId').val() != previousVal)
   {
     previousVal  = $('#elementId').val();
     $('#elementId').change();    
   }
}

setInterval(InputChangeListener, 500);

$('#elementId').val(3);
```

**Edit** based on comments for many elements.

You can use array and monitor, 30 element wont be a performance concern

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/9zeRH/3/)**

```
$('.someclass').change(function(){
   alert("changed, id >> " + this.id);
});

var hashTablePrevElem=[];
$('.someclass').each(function(){
   hashTablePrevElem[this.id] = this.value; 
});

function InputChangeListener()
{    
    $('.someclass').each(function(){ 
      if(hashTablePrevElem[this.id] != this.value)
      {
       hashTablePrevElem[this.id]  = this.value;
       $(this).change();    
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this may be the only way to do it. But I need to monitor about 30 input fields. I wonder how much of a performance problem it will be to poll their values repeatedly.

Comment: Using arrays could make it simple and fast.

Comment: I have made demo for ten elements, check my updated answer, I hope it wont be performance hit.

Comment: This could be improved slightly be extracting the `$('.someclass')` selector from within the `InputChangeListener` to outside, possibly utilising the `each` when initialising `hashTablePrevElem`.

Comment: We have to check all the input for change in InputChangeListener

Comment: That appears to work very nicely, Adil. That's what I'll do. Thank you.